# Armazenar a hora de um campo input type Time em uma coluna do tipo Time

Tags: php, input, time

Estou trabalhando em um website que agenda vistorias imobiliarias, e preciso armazenar no MySQL o horário que a pessoa solicitou a visita. Estou usando um campo input em HTML do tipo Time.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
O campo na tabela está no tipo de dados time com comprimento 6.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Quando tento inserir via SQL, via AJAX, não está funcionando.
Acredito que tenha algo relacionado a formatação do valor da hora...
Alguém pode me ajudar e orientar como devo proceder para efetuar a inserção do valor?

```
$txtDataVistoria_formatada = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($txtDataVistoria));

$txtHoraVistoria_pre = new DateTime($txtHoraVistoria);
$txtHoraVistoria_formatada = $txtHoraVistoria_pre->format('H:i:s.u');
```

Comment: Para `$txtHoraVistoria=14:30`  com `$txtHoraVistoria_formatada = date( 'H:i:s.u', strtotime($txtHoraVistoria) );`   teremos o resultado `14:30:00.000000` Pergunto: para que serve essa precisão no formato `s.u`?

Comment: Defini assim porque achei que como ao inserir manualmente via phpmyadmin ele disponibiliza está precisão, achei que via código PHP deveria passar o mesmo nível de precisão microssegundos... Mas realmente não sei se isto está correto.

Comment: Meu banco (MySQL)  para coluna time só aceita esse formato `14:30:00`

Comment: No meu quando Clico para inserir manualmente via PHP ele abre um slider pra cada dígito (hora, min, seg, miliseg, microseg)... Vou carregar uma foto depois...

Comment: Qual é seu banco?

Comment: Maria DB https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/microseconds-in-mariadb/

Comment: MySQL da Oracle

Comment: No meu abre assim  https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQqHi.png

Comment: Isso mesmo só que o meu possui Mili e micro segundos

Comment: Sua versão phpmyadmin deve ser mais atual, mas de qq forma acho que MySQL não aceita Mili e micro

Comment: Tudo bem, eu tbm não quero. Só preciso armazenar a hora é o minuto... Como fazer?

Comment: é só fazer o insert com o valor retornado via POST. Vai armazenar a hora o minuto e de quebra o 00 dos segundos automaticamente

Comment: No seu caso deve ser `$txtHoraVistoria` então ficaria `$txtHoraVistoria=$_POST['Name_Input']`

Comment: Obrigado Leo! Vou tentar fazer dessa forma a noite e te dou um retorno! Obrigado pela ajuda!